# Laravel 4 Facades Performance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there is any difference in performance using `static` or `non-static` methods in Laravel 4 `models`? The same question for custom classes. Should I use `Facades` with `ServiceProviders` to access custom class or just use classic OOP way? For instance which one would be faster to perform 1 million insert operations:

```
UserModel::insert($user);
```

vs

```
$UserModel = new UserModel();
$UserModel->insert($user);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `UserModel::insert($user)` is not a facade (Laravel Facades are resolved through the IoC container, which does incur some *minor* performance cost). [It just calls `__callStatic`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2805-L2810), and lets Eloquent create the new model instance for you.
2. Technically, creating your own instance would be faster, since you're doing exactly what Laravel does in `__callStatic`, so you're saving one function call. But the difference is so minuscule, as to not matter at all.

---

When I jump, am I closer to the sun than you are?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a big difference for performance in both approaches, when you use `Static` call to a model, it just calls the `__callstatic` magic method and from there, `Laravel` make an instance of the original class and call the method and if you manually make an instance of the original class and call the method manually then the `Facade` won't be used and that time the `Facade` uses to resolve the original class will be saved but it's not a very big difference.

So, in my opinion, you may use the common approach that `Laravel` provides and stay consistent but you are free. The, `static` call is an easy way to call the methods. Follow the common approach that everybody uses, it's better not to be different when you are working in a project with others.